# What is 'as' keyword doing in the following code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning 'Exceptions' in Python.
Consider the following code :

```
def fancy_divide():
    try:
        print(5/0)
    except Exception:
        print(Exception)
```

If I run the above code, ie

> fancy_divide()

it prints out `<class 'Exception'>`.
But if I modify the code :

```
def fancy_divide():
    try:
        print(5/0)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

It prints out 'division by zero' on calling the function `fancy_divide()`.
Why this difference?
I thought that the 'as' keyword is just to rename objects.

Comment: `Exception` is a class, `ex` is an object. `print(Exception)` will print `<class 'Exception'>` anywhere (as long as you dont declare a variable with this name), but `ex` will only exist inside its except scope

Comment: @Aran-Fey How were you able to write <class 'Exception'>??

Comment: @idpd15 I wrapped it in \`backticks\`

Comment: @RafaelC: I feel like you should write an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

It says that for scope following `as` there will be a variable called `ex` that was created from `Exception`.

In your case the difference is that in example one you are printing out the class Exception, in example two you are printing an object of type Exception.

```
>>> print(int)
<class 'int'>
>>> print(int(1))
1
>>>
```

I often see and use it when opening a file:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    f.read()
```

In python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) it has the following example:

```
>>> try:
...     raise NameError('HiThere')
... except NameError:
...     print('An exception flew by!')
...     raise
...
An exception flew by!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: HiThere
```

Notice that the Code doesn't do anything with the class `NameError`.  Because they are in that block they know that it's a `NameError`.   If they wanted to do something with the error object that was thrown then they would have to rewrite the code with `as`:

```
>>> try:
...     raise NameError('HiThere')
... except NameError as e:
...     print(e)
...     print('An exception flew by!')
...     raise
...
```

Answer (score 1):

On the last line of your first `fancy_divide` function, you printed the `Exeption` class itself, not an *instance* of the `Exception` class. On the third line of your updated code, where you used the `as` keyword, you were trying to catch an *instance* of the `Exception` class or its subclasses and assign it to the variable `ex` if you got an error. Note: an instance is different from the *actual* class (well, I hope you already know this)

You can see this when you compare the contents of `ex` to `Exception`:

```
def fancy_divide_return():
    try:
        print(5/0)
    except Exception as ex:
        return Exception, ex



>>> the_class, the_instance = fancy_divide_return()
>>> the_class
<class 'Exception'>
>>> the_instance
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)
>>> type(the_class)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(the_instance)
<class 'ZeroDivisionError'>
```